# Invite to share screen (iMessage) - Automation - How?

Tags: automator, remote-desktop

How can i automate an "Invite to share screen" from iMessages.

I share screens a lot with my colleagues and it would just make sense to have an option to quick ask someone to view my screen. Yet now, i have to look the user up in the imessage window and "target practice" the small icon, then Invite ..

Would be easier if i could automate it, or somehow create a desktop shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for an automative method to do this from within the *Messages* app, which this AppleScript can achieve.  You can place it in a **Run AppleScript** action.

```
use application "System Events"

property process : a reference to process "Messages"
property menu bar : a reference to menu bar 1 of my process
property menu bar item : a reference to menu bar item "Buddies" of my menu bar
property menu : a reference to menu 1 of my menu bar item

activate application "Messages"

set _M to a reference to (menu item "Invite to Share My Screen" in my menu)
tell _M to if not ((exists) and its enabled) then return false

click _M
```

However, it seems to me that, however this script is triggered, whether via an *Automator* service, *Keyboard Maestro*, the Scripts menu, or whatever; it will either require at least a couple of mouse clicks (e.g. to active a service from the context menu), or a keypress.

Therefore, in my mind, the easiest way to achieve the same outcome would be to set a keyboard shortcut for the appropriate menu item in *Messages*:

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts in macOS High Sierra]
<sup>**Keyboard Shortcuts in macOS High Sierra:** *System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shorcuts*</sup>

<strike>This screenshot is from High Sierra, so if you're running Mojave, it may be a little different.</strike>  The important things are to check the name of the relevant menu item in *Messages* in case it varies from High Sierra or you use a different language on your system; and to ensure that the entry you type for your App Shortcut is identical, including capitals and non-capitals used: so `"Invite to Share My Screen"` is **not** the same as `"Invite To Share My Screen"` and only the first one would work.

---

<sup>**ADDENDUM:** *(added 12 hours after original answer)*
[@user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) kindly reminded me that my style of scripting can sometimes appear a little obtuse and more difficult to follow and understand to novice scripters.  Therefore, I am posting a version of the above code that this user recommended.  Functionally, it does exactly the same as the original (apart from activating *Messages*, which doesn't need to be done if the application is already active and being used).  This version utilises less ambiguous syntax and more of AppleScript's (in)famous natural-language flavour:</sup>

```
try
    tell application "System Events" to click ¬
        menu item "Invite to Share My Screen" of ¬
        menu 1 of menu bar item "Buddies" of ¬
        menu bar 1 of process "Messages"
end try
```

Comment: Just an FYI... The info presented under macOS High Sierra is the exact same for macOS Mojave.

Comment: Also, I have to mention KISS again... your AppleScript, as currently coded, is a total of 465 characters and does the same thing as 197 characters with `activate application "Messages"` and `tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Invite to Share My Screen" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Buddies" of menu bar 1 of process "Messages"` wrapped in a `try` _block_. The latter, frankly, is IMO so much easier to understand what's happening. Of course scripting is not even needed in this scenario as a keyboard shortcut can be assigned to the Invite to Share My Screen command as you've noted.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I do love your advances scripting skills and have learned much from many of your answers; however, it seems obvious, based on the content of the question, that the OP isn't too familiar with AppleScript as he didn't even mention it specifically, yes I know in part I may be making an assumption. The point I'm trying to make is sometimes, and this is another one of them, for this particular use case... KISS is appropriate as in the code in my previous comment.

Comment: @user3439894 You are absolutely right, and I keep typing before I stop to think.  It just kinda comes out by reflex, but I need to learn to take a beat and adapt my answer to the person asking.  Btw, the `try` block wouldn’t be necessary: `tell app "System Events" to tell menu item "Invite to Share My Screen" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Buddies" of menu bar 1 of process "Messages" to if (exists) then click it". If run from within _Messages_, there’s no need to `activate` first (_Messges_ menu items don’t respond unless the app owns the menu bar, which isn’t the case for all apps).

Comment: Yes, there's certainly more then one way in this case to write a minimum of _code_. I used the `try` _block_ to negate the need to check to see it the menu item existed and was enabled, as in your original _code_. True though, if trigged while Messages owns the menu bar, and the target menu item exists, enabled or not, then this is all that's necessary `tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Invite to Share My Screen" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Buddies" of menu bar 1 of process "Messages"` Obviously, if it exists and is not enabled (the default), nothing else happens.

Comment: @user3439894 I added an addendum and borrowed your version of the code to add to my answer (with credit).  I hope that's okay (if not, either tell me and I'll remove it, or feel free to edit yourself).